# How ignore any files using HHVM proxygen rewrite rules?

Tags: php, hhvm, proxygen

I create a file like this `example.ini`:

```
hhvm.server.type = proxygen

hhvm.server.default_document = index.php

hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][pattern] = "(.*)"
hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][to] = "index.php/$1"
hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][qsa] = true
```

And calling in terminal:

```
$ hhvm -m server -p 9000 -d hhvm.server.source_root=/home/user/project -c example.ini
```

It's work fine, However I can still browse existing files that are in the same folder as the project, but what I would like is that all requests should be sent to *"index.php"*, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 100% of all request to go through the rewrite rules add this:

```
hhvm.virtual_host[default][check_existence_before_rewrite]= false
```

However, unless you're building an API or something with 100% dynamic content,  avoid this.  Static content like text, html files, images, etc... should be allowed to be served up without having to be evaluated in your PHP code.

I'd recommend keeping all sensitive files and code (except your index.php) outside your web root.  Only put static files like in this folder and of course your index.php, don't put other code in here.

Comment: Using `check_existence_before_rewrite` with `[conditions][c][negate] = false` allow ignore `check_existence_before_rewrite`, eg. if I need disable a unique directory (in my example `system/` see:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inphinit/inphinit/master/system/boot/hhvm.ini), If the file exists and is outside of "system", then the hhvm recognizes it again. Thanks again =) **Note:** `[common]` and `[c]` are "custom", you can change.